# Passing form values from thymeleaf to Control class and render Collection objects to another page

Tags: java, spring, forms, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I've recently discovered Thymeleaf but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use it. And I really need getting this done.

Basically I Have this method

```
public Collection renderHost(String Hostgroup, String startDate, String endDate){
    HostDao ho= new HostDao();
    ho.getAllHosts(Hostgroup);
    ho.generateObjects(startDate, endDate);
    return ho.getListaOgg().values();
}
```

So it returns a Collection of Host Objects

```
public class Host {
    private String deviceName;
    private String deviceIP; 
    private double connectionLoss; 
    private double responseTime; 
    private double packetLoss; 
    private String upTime; 
    private double cpuUtil;
    private double Temp; 
    private double memory;
}
```

I want that submitting this form:

```
<form th:action="/gethosts" method="post">
    <label>Hostgroup name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Hostgroup" id="Hostgroup">
    <label>Date start</label>
    <input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate" >
    <label>date end</label>
    <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" r>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

it passes the 3 variables to my controller class put it inside the method and the rendered Collections of objects to be passed to another thymeleaf page where I can use all the objects to create a table content using:

```
<th:foreach th:each="...">
    ...block to be repeated...
</th>
```

something like this. Sorry if my indications aren't that great. But I'm having a  hard time figuring out where to start, seaching the web only confuses me more.
Any help is aprecciated.

EDIT: added my attempt at setting the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gethosts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Model renderHost(@RequestParam("Hostgroup") String Hostgroup,
                        @RequestParam("dataInizio") String dateInizio,
                        @RequestParam("dataFine" ) String dateFine, Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("hostGroup", Hostgroup);
   model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateInizio);
   model.addAttribute("dateEnd", dateFine);
   return model;
}
```

Comment: And where is your controller code? Did you try doing a simple form first, like this tutorial here? https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: What are you actually asking for ? What do you want to know because I don't understand your post.

Comment: I've updated the post adding the controller method. I don't know how to configure the form to pass the values to my controller, and how to use the controller method to retrieve those 3 values and pass it to my renderHost method.

Comment: I've tried several tutorial , but nothing is remotely close with what I want. And I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you send your form as post and you have get method in controller. Second thing is your controller method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/gethosts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public **String** renderHost(@RequestParam("Hostgroup") String Hostgroup,
                             @RequestParam("dataInizio") String dateInizio,
                             @RequestParam("dataFine" ) String dateFine ,   Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("hostGroup", Hostgroup);
   model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateInizio);
   model.addAttribute("dateEnd", dateFine);
   return  "put your html page name";
     }
```

or:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/gethosts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView renderHost(@RequestParam("Hostgroup") String Hostgroup,
                             @RequestParam("dataInizio") String dateInizio,
                             @RequestParam("dataFine" ) String dateFine) {
   ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("put your html page name");
   model.addAttribute("hostGroup", Hostgroup);
   model.addAttribute("dateStart", dateInizio);
   model.addAttribute("dateEnd", dateFine);
   return  model;
     }
```

In your controller you just return model without any information about template that you use.
Change your form method to "GET" if you want to do this that way.
I suggest you to create a form class when you have fields that you want to use in your html form. Then you just send this POST method and in controller method retrieve information from form.

More information here: 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Going to give it a try! Thank you so much. It made things a little bit clearer

Comment: Let me know when you do some progress

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this as a POST request, thy this one.

Create Host.java class.

```
public class Host  {
    private String hostGroup;
    private String dateStart;
    private String dateEnd;

   // add getters and setters as well
}
```

Write a method to render the page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/renderPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String renderPage( Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    {

        model.addAttribute("host", new Host() );

        return "page";
    }
```

Method to handle POST request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gethosts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String renderHost( @ModelAttribute("Host") Host host )
    {

  }
```

And change the html accordingly.

```
<form th:action="/gethosts" method="post" th:object="${host}">
    <label>Hostgroup name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="host.hostgroup" id="Hostgroup">
    <label>Date start</label>
    <input type="date" name="host.startDate" id="startDate" >
     <label>date end</label>
    <input type="date" name="host.endDate" id="endDate" r>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">

  </form>
```